# Android drop imageview over other imageview which is same in size

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, imageview

I am making buzzle game in which drag one view(ex Ball) and drop on the same dimenssional view (Ex Ball_1) how to change the drop target to the drag image.

Comment: What code do you have? What isn't working? What have you tried? What *exactly* do you want to do? ("match both imageview" is not very specific)

Comment: want to place one Imageview on to other imageview which are same.

Comment: Update the question - don't clarify as a comment.

Comment: I understand English is not your first language but you have to help us out here with a bit more detail. Are you asking how to overlay images in your layout or via code (which would not make sense if they are the same size) or are you asking how to let the user drag one image and drop it over the other thereby replacing it?

Comment: If you can improve this question so the question is clear, please flag your question for moderator attention to be reviewed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking 2 questions, the first is how to do drag and drop, the second is how to change the drop target to the drag image, you should really break these into two questions and give a lot more detail as to what your end goal is (Is this a puzzle game etc) a lot of people will be irritated with your lack of english skills (I am not one of those) so you need to work extra hard to try and be detailed and clear.

If that is what you are tyring to do then take a look here [Drag and Drop ImageView Tutorial](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/moving-views-part-2/) and instead of overlaying it just change the drop image resource to the drag images resource, this should get you moving in the right direction.

If this works for you then accept the answer, if not provide more detail